# C++ refactoring of function

Tags: c++, function, refactoring, inline

I have an array of numbers, for example: 1,2,3,4,5...,10

For every item the following function is called:

```
    do
     {
      if (..)
        {
         return_val= performsomething (parm1,parm2..parm5);
        }
     }
```

The function `performsomething()` is written like below:

```
    performsomething (x1,x2,...)
    {
     if (A_req?)
      {
       performA();
      }
     else if (B_req?)
      {
      performB();
      }
    }
```

Now, if it is seen closely, for every item the function `performsomething()` is getting called.

I want to avoid the performance overhead of these many function calls. I want to refactor the method `performsomething()` like it will check the conditions `A_req?` or `B_req?`. Accordingly, it will call `performA()` or `performB()`. I want to make `performsomething()` as 'inline' and call the underlying functions as needed.

Please help me how to code efficiently to achieve the above requirement .!.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and use a loop, instead of multiple parameters maybe? The example you show doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: What are `A_req` etc? When and where are those defined or declared? Could you perhaps use object and inheritance and polymorphism instead? Or templates? Or do the selection in the loop instead?

Comment: The global optimizer will probably do this for you.  If you want to manually inline your function, just copy-paste the code in your loop, puting it in a block, and starting the bloc by defining block variables x1..xn initializing them wiht param1..paramn,  and replace all the (missing) return statements in an assignement to return_val...

Comment: can somebody post a sample code snippet ?